# Hive timestamp comparison issue

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table where I want to filter out data based on the updated timestamp. 
I have a table `test_table` which has a timestamp column called "updated_timestamp".
When I run :

`select max(ZIW_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP) from test_table;`
It returns : 2016-08-09 11:00:48.849
But when I run :

`select count(*) from  test_table where  UPDATED_TIMESTAMP = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-08-09 11:00:48.849' , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'));`
it returns 0.

This exact timestamp is being used in ~5000 rows. I am not sure what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out a solution :
Instead of using from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2016-08-09 11:00:48.849' , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'));
I converted the timestamp column to unix timestamp column.

`select count(*) from  test_table where unix_timestamp( UPDATED_TIMESTAMP,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') = unix_timestamp('2016-08-09 11:00:48.849' , 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS');`
This works fine.